# Duda sobre "escuálido" en el pronunciamiento de un Ministro

Tags: selección-de-palabras, uso-de-palabras, vocabulario, modismos, venezuela

Viendo este pronunciamiento del Ministro de Educación de Venezuela

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BKW8nloZAqQ

en el 00:18 el dice estas palabras

> no es que vamos a sacar la gente de la pobreza, pa' llevarla a la clase media pa' que después aspiren a ser "escuálidos"

Segun el RAE

```
escuálido, da.
(Del lat. squalĭdus).
1. adj. Flaco, macilento.
2. adj. Sucio, asqueroso.
3. adj. Zool. Se dice de los peces selacios que tienen el cuerpo fusiforme, hendiduras     branquiales a los lados, detrás de la cabeza, y cola robusta; p. ej., el cazón y la lija. U.   t. c. s.
4. m. pl. Zool. Suborden de estos peces.
```

¿Qué quiso decir con esa frase?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extraído de [cronicasvenezuela](http://cronicasvenezuela.com/2013/12/27/los-venezolanos-esculidos-o-camlidos/)

> Uno de los insultos más populares que divulgó, el ya habitante del más allá, Hugo Chávez, fue el de “escuálido”, que en una acepción significa flaco, macilento, asqueroso, pero en otra acepción constituye el orden de los peces escualos, grandes depredadores temidos hasta por el hombre. Rápidamente, en algunos mitines o marchas de la oposición muchos jóvenes lucieron franelas, con la imagen de un tiburón diciendo, “soy escuálido y qué”.

Una búsqueda en Twitter de la palabra y veras que la gran mayoría son gente de Venezuela.

https://twitter.com/search?q=escualidos&src=typd

Resumiendo, una nueva definición en Venezuela usada en el ámbito político.

Comment: es usada en tono peyorativo entoncespor el gobierno en venezuela

Comment: por eso te decia no entendia bien, pq dice sacar a la gente de la pobreza y llevarlos a la clase media, pa que aspiren a ser (flacos,asquerosos) escuálidos. como que no tiene mucho sentido no?

Comment: Es un termino para denigrar al que esta en la oposición, el Ministro del vídeo lo uso adrede y además se ríe al final. Chavez se la debió inventar en algún discurso acompañado seguramente de la palabra fascistas.